# adding/removing my cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, npm, cordova-plugins

I made a cordova plugin for Android applications, but unlike other plugins, this one only uses an Application (App.java) and not a CordovaPlugin class.

When I try to install it for the first time using cordova plugin add, it works fine. When I try to remove it using cordova plugin rm, it doesn't remove the folder from node_modules and keeps the plugin dependency name in the package.json. Besides, it removes some code from the manifest that belongs to another plugin (I've seen this is a consecuence of the edit-file in the plugin.xml, I need to add the Application name to the manifest) and if I try to install it again I will get an error (because it's still holding the node_modules dependency) unless I update the version of the plugin.

Here's my plugin.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" id="com.test.plugin.applicationTest" version="1.0.0" platform = "Android">
   <name>codova-app-plugin</name>
   <description>Test</description>
   <author>test</author>

   <license>Apache 2.0</license>

   <keywords>cordova, application</keywords>


   <platform name="android">
      <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
         <feature name="applicationTest">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.test.plugin.applicationTest" />
         </feature>
      </config-file>

      <source-file src="src/android/App.java" target-dir="src/com/test/plugin/applicationTest" />      

       <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
       </config-file>

      <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
         <application android:name="com.test.plugin.applicationTest.App"/>
      </edit-config>

   </platform>
</plugin>
```

Why it isn't removing the node_modules? and what can I do to avoid the deletion of the AndroidManifest tags ?

Edit:
If I remove the edit-config and instead use a hook, I won't delete the AndroidManifest tags, but they won't get executed or throw EACCESS error. Besides, it keeps the node_modules dependencies.

```
   <hook type="after_plugin_install" src="scripts/nameManifest.js" /> -- won't execcute
   <hook type="before_plugin_uninstall" src="scripts/uninstallPackage.sh" /> -- EACCESS error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the best I can do is to remove that edit-config and create hooks for the edition of the application name and the execution of npm uninstall